# Servlet mapping not working on production, but working on localhost

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet mapping like below.

```xml
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>SubmitComment</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.rohitsharma.db.servlet.SubmitComment</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>SubmitComment</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/SubmitComment</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

When I hit a form with action `SubmitComment`. It worked on my localhost.
But when I uploaded it on real host it give me error like.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /SubmitComment was not found on this server.

How should I change these mapping to get it working?

Here is the form:

```html
 <form action="SubmitComment" method="post" id="leavereply">
      <ol><li>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" class="text" />
      </li><li>
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" class="text" />
      </li><li>
        <label for="message">Your Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
      </li>
        <input type="hidden" id="blog_id" name="blog_id" value="<%out.print(blog.blog_id);%>">
      <li>
        <input type="image" name="imageField" id="imageField" src="images/submit.gif" class="send" />
        <div class="clr"></div>
      </li></ol>
      </form>
```

Comment: seems like deployment issue , make sure it deployed without any issues!

Comment: maybe you are using a context in the production environment /context/SubmitComment

Comment: didn't get it ?. and yes everything is deployed well. 
Is the pattern i wrote above is correct

Comment: can anyone tell that how to append this context against the resource

Comment: http://www.abc.org/SubmitComment this is what is in the url bar when error arrives

Comment: atleast i learned about Error Page Redirection Due to This :)

Comment: The servlet might just have failed to initialize. Read the server startup logs and mention inconsitenties here. Perhaps there's a missing/outdated dependency or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was server setting issue. Nothing related to the code or any mapping.
Thanks for your time. It was some setting issue on my live hosts. I changed my host and things worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you prepend the form's `action` with the context root, when constructing the HTML?
What's rendered to the client's browser should be `/<context-root>/SubmitComment`. It is possible that, on your local server, the application is deployed on the default context root whereas it is deployed on a different context root in production.

Show us the code you use for rendering the URL on the HTML form. You're probably missing `<c:url>` there.

Comment: Yes, that is your problem then. You should be prepending "SubmitComment" with the context root under which the application is deployed. You can get this value at runtime. Read the reference for the `url` tag in the `core` JSTL library. Alternatively, you can use `request.getContextPath()` for this.

Comment: should i be writing it as action="<%out.println(request.getContextPath)%>/SubmitComment"

Comment: @Issac can you please give an example of how to prepend action. Coz i tried above it made my localhost stop working

Comment: @Javanator, there are a few ways to do this. The way that you described above should work, but it'd be better to use JSTL's "url" tag from the "core" taglib. See here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm

Comment: This can hardly be the cause based on the URL in `<form action>` and the URL in 404 error message. The cause is elsewhere.

Comment: @BalusC, explain please. Note that the fragment containing the form might also be taken from a dynamically-included JSP file which might be elsewhere in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where it works locally and doesn't work in my dev environment. The error would say that the page was not found. It turns out that it was an Apache httpd configuration where I had to make a JKMount entry to virtual_hosts.conf. After I restarted the httpd service, I was able to hit it.

This is a case where the problem is something not code or settings related but maybe this may be helpful for someone else if they have a Apache httpd service layer in front of their servlet container.